# Ip6tables DNAT on openwrt is not working

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv6, ip6tables

I configure ipv6 dnat using ip6tables on my openwrt router:

```
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 5100 -j DNAT --to-destination fdca:3aae:fe2e::1:53 # fdca:3aae:fe2e::1 is my router address
```

Then testing it on other linux server by dig like this:

```
dig -6 www.google.com @fdca:3aae:fe2e::1 -p5100
```

Dig failed with connection timed out after seconds. But the ip6tables pkts counter added 1 after executing the dig command. And tcpdump show that router received the udp packet but without reply. I tested ipv4 like this and succeed. So why did ipv6 failed?

TCPDUMP packets:

> 16:29:16.914206 IP6 fdca:3aae:fe2e:0:5054:ff:fe32:8d8b.48898 > fdca:3aae:fe2e::1.5100: UDP, length 43

ip6tables -t nat -L -x -n -v show:

> Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 91 bytes)
>       pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>          8      728 DNAT       udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:5100 to:fdca:3aae:fe2e::1:53

cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack | grep 5100 show:

> ipv6     10 udp      17 56 src=fdca:3aae:fe2e:0000:5054:00ff:fe32:8d8b
>   dst=fdca:3aae:fe2e:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 sport=47169 dport=5100
>   packets=1 bytes=91 [UNREPLIED]
>   src=fdca:3aae:fe2e:0000:0000:0000:0001:0053
>   dst=fdca:3aae:fe2e:0000:5054:00ff:fe32:8d8b sport=5100 dport=47169
>   packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 zone=0 use=2

Comment: Does your destination host actually use the OpenWRT box as its gateway, i.e. send replies back through the same system? Routing must be symmetric for NAT to work properly.

Comment: Don't attempt to NAT with IPv6, route instead.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you need to protect IPv6 address with `[]`:

```
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 5100 -j DNAT --to-destination [fdca:3aae:fe2e::1]:53 # fdca:3aae:fe2e::1 is my router address
```

This should also work and is simpler:

```
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 5100 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```